# didRecieveMemoryWarning in ARC (iOS / Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, ios, debugging, automatic-ref-counting, didreceivememorywarning

I have an iOS (Obj-C) project that uses ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). According to Apple Documentation, and pure experimentation, you cannot have statements such as:

```
[UIThingamabob release];
```

This was previously the way to release items after being allocated or retained. Now I do know that you have to manage how IB objects are created in the

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ...
```

portion of your header file.

I've been using the above statement as it is (with the nonatomic and retain (or strong- what's the difference anyway, how are they used?) properties) for all of my IB items. When I test on an iOS Device, I'll randomly get a UIAlertView (that I created for debugging purposes) that only displays when the *didRecieveMemoryWarning* event is fired.

Some of my BETA testers are bombarded with these views nonstop until they manage to quit the app.

My question is, **what do I put in the didRecieveMemoryWarning event since I can't release objects**? If there isn't anything to put there, then are these errors occurring due to the way I create my objects with the @property function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet...` for all of your IBOutlets. If you use strong, the outlet is retained by the view controller and by it's superview. When the view disappears, the view controller still has a reference to that outlet which is no longer visible. You could set the outlet property to nil in `-viewDidUnload` or by using weak setting the pointer to nil is done automatically when the view disappears.

Comment: +1 For a good point ^^.  However, in the case of external objects in your NIB (i.e. outside the view hierarchy), you might still want to use strong so they aren't immediately deallocated.

Comment: @borrrden: Nothing can be _outside_ the view hierarchy, although views can be top-level, and those should be strong references. The window is the superview of everything else.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau Let me give you an example.  I have several toggle buttons in my view hierarchy, and in order to ensure that only one is clicked at a time for each section, I insert some NSObject based Group objects as type "Object" in my nib at the top level.  Since they are not children of the UIViewController's view and actually not displayed at all, this is what I mean by outside the view hierarchy.  If I don't have a strong reference to them, they will be deallocated upon creation.

Comment: @borrrden: Oh, I see, non-view objects.

Comment: Does it matter which order: (weak, nonatomic) or (nonatomic, weak)? Also, great answer!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `retain` in the `@property` statement. The ARC options are `assign`, `weak` and `strong`. For more details, see here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

In particular, check the part on Property Attributes!

edit: Thanks for the comments, both `retain` and `strong` seem to be equivalent right now.

Comment: That's really helpful, +1, but in the event that there is a memory warning, how should I handle it with ARC?

Comment: Retain is still perfectly valid, see here:  http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property

Comment: I thought strong and retain were analogous.

Comment: Ok, I should have read more closely. I guess you should be more careful with the properties that are indispensable (i.e. the strong/retained properties), and use weak/assign for everything else. If all your properties are strong, ARC can't do it's job ;)

Comment: @thundersteele The biggest problem is retain cycles (i.e. properties that have strong references to each other).  You use weak references to break retain cycles :).  If you don't, then those objects will never be deallocated.  Using weak for as much as possible won't help, you need to nil out objects when a memory warning comes.  This will help them on the path to deallocation.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to know what to do without seeing your project but you can do things like:

Clear out arrays of data that you can regenerate later.  Clear buffers.  Set currently unused objects to nil (which will release them if they are not retained elsewhere).